# Notify-send not working in python script run with sudo

Tags: python, bash, notifications, sudo, notify-send

I'm writing a python script that is run with sudo permissions. At some point, I would like to send a notification to the user. I have noticed that notify-send does not work as a root user, so I tried to run it as the actual user by doing `su $SUDO_USER -c notify-send ...`, but this does not work either.

The first of the following functions works when run without sudo privileges. None of them work when run with sudo. Any idea why?

```
def notify(message):

    subprocess.run(['notify-send', '-i', 'utilities-terminal', 'Notification Title', message],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                   check=True)


def notifySudo(message):

    subprocess.run(['su', os.environ['SUDO_USER'], '-c', 'notify-send', '-i', 'utilities-terminal', 'Notification Title', message],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                   check=True)
```

Comment: You must get the DISPLAY an XAUTHORITY user env var to print something on his screen.

Comment: @ctac_ I've tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0` (as seen in another posts) and also I've seen in some other questions this one `eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gdm-x-session)/environ)"` but it's not working yet. Could you give some more insight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a bit of research, I've found the solution:

```
import os

def notify(title, message):

    userID = subprocess.run(['id', '-u', os.environ['SUDO_USER']],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            check=True).stdout.decode("utf-8").replace('\n', '')


    subprocess.run(['sudo', '-u', os.environ['SUDO_USER'], 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/{}/bus'.format(userID), 
                    'notify-send', '-i', 'utilities-terminal', title, message],
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    check=True)
```